# Jenkins Pipeline push the Docker Image

Tags: docker, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to push my docker image after building source code, when jenkins push images to docker Hub Registry i am getting below error.

Pipeline Script

```
stage('Build Docker Image') {
        container('docker') {
            echo 'docker'
            sh "docker build -t ${image_name} ."
            sh "docker tag ${image_name} ${image_name}:${image_tag}"          
        }
      } 

    stage('Push Docker Image') {
        container('docker') {
        withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS', variable: 'DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS')]) {
        sh "docker login -u user-name -p ${DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS}"
          }
          sh "docker push ${image_name}:${image_tag}"
       }
    }
```

Jenkins Logs

```
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Push Docker Image)
[Pipeline] container
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $DOCKER_HUB_CREDENTIALS
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker login -u user-name -p ****
Login Succeeded
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker push devopsimage.azure/frontend:bug-fix-2cbb925d
The push refers to repository [devopsimage.azure/frontend]
Get https://devopsimage.azure/v2/: dial tcp: lookup devopsimage.azure.io: Temporary failure in name resolution
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // podTemplate
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

Can you please any one help me on this ?

Comment: This looks to be a DNS-related issue. How is DNS configured on your Jenkins host?

Comment: Separately, I'd suggest using [`docker.build().push()`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/#building-containers) instead of scripting `sh "docker ..."` commands; there's a path to specify an alternate registry and provide credentials.

Answer (score 0):

If you have dot(.) in your image name before the slash, docker treats it as the registry name. So docker push is trying to push to registry named `devopsimage.azure`. If you actually want to push to Docker Hub instead, remove the dot from the image name. If you want to push to registry named `devopsimage.azure`, then there is a DNS issue in resolving this registry from your build machine.